# Javascript/NodeJs optimize repeated if-else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

how i can refactor/rewrite the code below in order to improve readability and Maintainability?
I have two main branch and into each branch i have the same if-else chain with 3 option and 3 sub-option. In total i have 9 leafs with 9 different functions to execute.

```
function selectFunctionToRun(){
    if (isFirstOption()) {
        if(isAlpha()){
            if(isXRay()){
                 do1();
            }else if (isYankee()){
                 do2();
            }else if (isZebra()){
                 do3();
            }
        }else if (isBeta()){
            if(isXRay()){
                 do4();
            }else if (isYankee()){
                 do5();
            }else if (isZebra()){
                 do6();
            }
        }else if (isCharlie()){
            if(isXRay()){
                 do7();
            }else if (isYankee()){
                 do8();
            }else if (isZebra()){
                 do9();
            }
        }
    }
    else if(isSecondOption(){
        if(isAlpha()){
            if(isXRay()){
                do11();
            }else if (isYankee()){
                do12();
            }else if (isZebra()){
                do13();
            }
        }else if (isBeta()){
            if(isXRay()){
                do14();
            }else if (isYankee()){
                do15();
            }else if (isZebra()){
                do16();
            }
        }else if (isCharlie()){
            if(isXRay()){
                do17();
            }else if (isYankee()){
                do18();
            }else if (isZebra()){
                do19();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming the values of `isFirstOption()`, `isSecondOption()` are dynamic, is this correct?

Comment: Are those 18 functions really that different from each other?

Comment: Thanks for replies. The answers to these questions are yes and yes. In my real project i have 4 options and 36 different functions. I wrote only two options for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is more concise, but I'm not sure if it's worth the effort for you.
I added some extra complexity in each case in case none of the options are true.  If one of them is guaranteed, you can avoid the whole "abort" logic.

```
var functionMap = {
    firstOption: {
        alpha: { xRay: do1, yankee: do2, zebra: do3 },
        beta: { xRay: do4, yankee: do5, zebra: do6 },
        charlie: { xRay: do7, yankee: do8, zebra: do9 }
    },
    secondOption: {
        alpha: { xRay: do11, yankee: do12, zebra: do13 },
        beta: { xRay: do14, yankee: do15, zebra: do16 },
        charlie: { xRay: do17, yankee: do18, zebra: do19 }
    }

};

function selectFunctionToRun() {
    var option = (isFirstOption()) ? "firstOption" : (isSecondOption()) ? "secondOption" : "abort";
    var abc = (isAlpha()) ? "alpha" : (isBeta()) ? "beta" : (isCharlie()) ? "charlie" : "abort";
    var xyz = (isXRay()) ? "xRay" : (isYankee()) ? "yankee" : (isZebra()) ? "zebra" : "abort";
    if (option != "abort" && abc != "abort" && xyz != "abort") {
        functionMap[option][abc][xyz].call();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the `isX` functions can be further simplified to directly return the `option`, `abc` and `xyz` values, so +1 :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks.  Yes, at least in the example, it sounds like we really just want to be looking at a single data member's value, but I figured NodeJsBeginner must have a reason for the added complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly restructure your if/else/elseif structures into something more like this:

```
var cases = {
    1: do1,
    2: do2,
    3: do3
};

if (cases[something]) {
    cases[something]();
}
```

source: [How to avoid switch case syndrome](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/how-to-avoid-switch-case-syndrome/)

Comment: It's similar to what Scott posted above. His answer is much detailed though. Props to Scott.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to +Scott 's solution

```
var functionMap = {
    _1AX: do1, _1AY: do2, _1AZ: do3, 
    _1BX: do4, _1BY: do5, _1BZ: do6, 
    _1CX: do7, _1CY: do8, _1CZ: do9,

    _2AX: do11, _2AY: do12, _2AZ: do13, 
    _2BX: do14, _2BY: do15, _2BZ: do16,
    _2CX: do17, _2CY: do18, _2CZ: do19
  }

function selectFunctionToRun () {
  var index = (isFirstOption () ? '_1' : isSecondOption() ? '_2' : '') +
              (isAlpha () ? 'A' : isBeta () ? 'B' : isCharlie () ? 'C' : '') +
              (isXRay () ? 'X' : isYankee () ? 'Y' : isZebra () ? 'Z' : '';

  (functionMap [index] || function error () { ... }) (index);
```

You could eliminate the `functionMap` if you name your handler functions according to the property names.